# With WinUI 3 and C#, how do I make ListView items not selectable (IsHitTestVisible="False") but still make CheckBox controls checkable?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winui-3, winui

I have the following XAML code:

```
<ListView x:Name="filterListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding SubIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SubFilterName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This code allows me to select `ListView` items like this:

[image]

What I want is for only the `CheckBox` to be checkable, not the actual rows selectable, so it would look like this all the time no matter where I click:

[image]

I have tried adding the following changes but it just makes *nothing* selectable/clickable at all:

```
<ListView IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="filterListView" >

<CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="True" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding SubIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Anyone have an ideas on what I can do to make this work how I'd like? `CheckBox`'s checkable, everything else not selectable.**

Comment: Try using `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` and set your property to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `SelectionMode` to `None`.